# play framework sorm intellij - cannot resolve symbol sorm

Tags: scala, playframework, frameworks, sorm

I'm using play framework 2.4.2. I added `"org.sorm-framework" % "sorm" % "0.3.16"` to my build.sbt, and run `update` while in activator console in my app. It downloaded package properly, however my IntelliJ does not see sorm.

When I write
`import sorm._` i get response `Cannot resolve symbol sorm`.

What should i do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should refresh your sbt project in intellij by clicking `View -> Tool Windows -> SBT -> Refresh all sbt projects`